# Software to backup/restore these settings in Windows

Tags: windows, backup, windows-10, windows-registry

Freshly reinstalling Windows you lose a lot of settings.
Even if you have backup finding out and restoring these settings is tedious. 
Is there a software that backs up and restores these automatically?

- [Hosts file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file))

  ```
  %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
  ```
- [Environment Variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/573817/where-are-environment-variables-stored-in-registry)

  ```
  HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment
  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment
  ```
- Run dialog box history

  ```
  HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\RunMRU
  ```
- CMD.exe font/layout options, etc.
- [Quick Access Toolbar](http://winaero.com/blog/backup-quick-access-toolbar-buttons-in-windows-10)

  ```
  HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Ribbon
  ```
- [Quick Access Folder items](https://superuser.com/questions/1051440/where-are-the-win-10-quick-access-settings-stored)

  ```
  %AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\AutomaticDestinations\f01b4d95cf55d32a.automaticDestinations-ms
  ```
- [Folders views (list, details, etc.) for different folder types (General items, documents, etc.)](https://superuser.com/questions/253249/windows-registry-entries-for-default-explorer-view)

  ```
  HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Streams\Settings
  ```
- [VPN settings](https://superuser.com/questions/312338/how-to-import-export-vpn-settings-in-windows-7)

  ```
  %AppData%\Microsoft\Network\Connections\Pbk
  %ProgramData%\Microsoft\Network\Connections\Pbk
  ```
- Power Plan settings

  ```
  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ControlPanel\NameSpace\{025A5937-A6BE-4686-A844-36FE4BEC8B6D}
  ```

Comment: What version of Windows? Does Windows Easy Transfer copy too much information over?

Comment: @PaulNijjar Windows 10. It seems Windows Easy Transfer is discontinued, there's a third party tool now called [Laplink PCmover Express](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/transfer-your-data) provided by MS, but it's a "transfer" tool and requires 2 PCs to be connected simultaneously which doesn't work for me as I was only reinstalling windows on my single PC. I prefer a backup/restore solution. Also it doesn't let me choose, or even show me what settings it's going to transfer.