# Apply my preferred settings on new Windows installation

Tags: windows-10, productivity, migration

When I install a new PC from scratch (either personal or by the company), I find myself changing a lot of settings each time, like

- turn off indexing on drives
- disable the search box in the task bar
- unpin Edge from the task bar
- never group buttons on the task bar
- never group buttons on secondary task bars
- show task bar buttons only on the monitor that has the corresponding window
- don't show news in task bar
- disable Cortana in task bar
- do not restart after a blue screen
- set pagefile to RAM size + 2 GB so that a full kernel dump fits in
- turn off PC when pressing power button
- maximum of 99% CPU on all power profiles to prevent Turbo Boost
- set screen scaling to 100%
- expand screen to multiple monitors instead of mirroring
- use small symbols in control panels
- disable animation effects
- set the "no sounds" sound scheme
- don't show most used apps in start menu
- don't show recently added apps in start menu

And potentially (other people might want this, I don't need it until now, since the default settings are ok for me)

- Clear Type settings
- Screen background
- Color theme
- Screen resolution
- Screen saver and screen saver timeout
- mouse cursor

The tool that achieves this should

- work with Windows 10
- cost less than 30 €

Optional / ideal

- ideally support other programs such as settings from MS Office
- it would be super cool if it could apply a subset of these settings temporarily, e.g. while I'm working with the system (like "admin mode") and restore the old settings when I leave. This would exclude expensive settings like turning off indexing of the hard drive.

On this site I found some similar requests:

- [this](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/74165/which-software-can-i-use-to-transfer-windows-10-to-a-new-hard-drive) question which is about changing the hard drive and migrating everything. I clearly want to do this on a new installation.
- [this](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/53409/is-there-a-software-to-backup-my-windows-10-settings-and-some-important-apps-wit?rq=1) one is more looking for a backup of the whole system. I need a fresh installation and then change settings.
- [this](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/35510/software-to-backup-restore-these-settings-in-windows) is looking for setting migration from the old PC to the new PC, but not the whole system. This is probably similar, except that I don't want to involve an old PC. Also, the kind of settings is different.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft recently released a tool called [Power Automate](https://flow.microsoft.com) (formerly Microsoft Flow), which I'm pretty sure has the ability to do what you want to achieve. Alternatively you could use an  [automated installation script](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/automate-windows-setup)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll check Power Automate. I am not looking for an automated installation script. This is already run by my IT department, so Windows is installed, there's a virus scanner available etc. My request is more about the details, the fine tuning.